# Boost Confidence of Overlapping Observations In Apache Spark

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, networking, distributed-computing

I'm fairly new to scala/spark, so forgive me if my question is elementary but I've searched everywhere and can't find the answer.

**Problem**

I'm trying to boost the confidence scores a bunch of network router observations (observations of probable router types at different network junctions).

I have a type `NetblockObservation` combines device types seen on a network with an associated netblock and a confidence. The confidence is the confidence that we accurately identified which device the device we saw.

```
case class NetblockObservation(
                      device_type: String
                      ip_start: Long,
                      ip_end: Long,
                      confidence: Double
                    )
```

If the confidence is above some threshold `thresh`, then I want that observation to be in the returned dataset. If it's below `thresh`, it should not be.

In addition if I have two observations with the same device_type and that one contains the other, the containee should have its confidence increased by by the confidence of the container.

**Example**

Let's say I have 3 Netblock Observations

```
// 0.0.0.0/28
NetblockObservation(device_type: "x", ip_start: 0, ip_end: 15, confidence_score: .4)
// 0.0.0.0/29
NetblockObservation(device_type: "x", ip_start: 0, ip_end: 7, confidence_score: .4)
// 0.0.0.0/30
NetblockObservation(device_type: "x", ip_start: 0, ip_end: 3, confidence_score: .4)
```

With a confidence threshold of 1, I would expect to have a single output of `NetblockObservation(device_type: "x", ip_start: 0, ip_end: 4, confidence_score: 1.2)`

**Explanation**: I am allowed to add the confidence scores of NetblockObservation's together if it's contained and has the same device_type

I was allowed to add the confidence score of the `0.0.0.0/29` to the confidence of the `0.0.0.0/30` because it's contained within it.

I was not allowed to add the confidence score of `0.0.0.0/30` to the `0.0.0.0/29` because `0.0.0.0/29` is not contained within `0.0.0.0/30`.

**My (pitiful) Attempt**

Failure reason: Too slow / never completed

I attempted to implement this while simultaneously learning scala/spark so I'm not sure if it's the idea or the implementation which is wrong. I think it would eventually work but after an hour, it hadn't completed on a dataset of size 300,000 (small compared to production scale) so I gave up on it.

The idea is to find the largest netblock and separate the data into netblocks which are contained and netblocks which are not contained. The netblocks which are not contained are recursively passed back into the same function. If the largest netblock has a confidence_score of 1, the entire contained dataset is disregarded and the largest is added to return dataset. If the confidence_score is less then 1, then its confidence_score is added to everything in the contained dataset and that group is recursively passed back to the same function. Eventually, you should only be left with the data which has a confidence_score greater then 1. This algorithm also has the issue of not taking device_type into account.

```
def handleDataset(largestInNetData: Option[NetblockObservation], netData: RDD[NetblockObservation]): RDD[NetblockObservation] = {
  if (netData.isEmpty) spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD else largestInNetData match {
    case Some(largest) =>
      val grouped = netData.groupBy(item =>
        if (item.ip_start >= largest.ip_start && item.ip_end <= largest.ip_end) largestInNetData
        else None)

      def lookup(k: Option[NetblockObservation]) = grouped.filter(_._1 == k).flatMap(_._2)

      val nos = handleDataset(None, lookup(None))
      // Threshold is assumed to be 1
      val next = if (largest.confidence_score >= 1) spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(largest)) else
        handleDataset(None, lookup(largestInNetData)
          .filter(x => x != largest)
          .map(x => x.copy(confidence_score = x.confidence_score + largest.confidence_score)))
      nos ++ next
    case None =>
      val largest = netData.reduce((a: NetblockObservation, b: NetblockObservation) => if ((a.ip_end - a.ip_start) > (b.ip_end - b.ip_start)) a else b)
      handleDataset(Option(largest), netData)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a fairly involved bit of code, so here is a general algorithm that I hope will help:

- Forget about Spark for a moment and write a Scala function, probably in the companion object for `NetblockObservation`, that takes a collection of them and returns a subset of that collection that is contained. You should unit test the heck out of this function, and again this is pure Scala.
- Moving now to Spark. Do a `groupBy` on your `RDD[NetblockObservation]` with `device_type` as the key producing essentially a map of `String` to `Iterable[NetblockObservation]`.
- Filter out all the entries in the map that have a value of size 1 *and* have a `confidence` below `thresh`.
- For the entries that remain, apply your function from the first step to the collections of `NetblockObservation`s with a `mapValues`.
- Do a `reduceByKey` or similar to simply add up the `confidence_score`s of the contained values.
- Enjoy a refreshing beverage.